# xmlns replace in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to xsl

**Input xml**

This is a input that i have used

```
        <enc xmlns="v9">
        <rnp xmsns="v2">
             <ele1 line="1">
              <ele2></ele2>
                </ele1>
        </rnp>
<Request xmlns="v1">
    <Info>
        <Country>US</Country>
        <Part>A</Part>
    </Info>
</Request>
</enc>
```

**XSL**
using xslt 1.0.

I am using below xsl.

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:variable name="var1">
    <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$var1='Request'">
       <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="v2"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/> 
        </xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

</xsl:stylesheet>

**Actual output**

This is output which i am getting using above snippets

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<enc xmlns="v9">
   <rnp xmsns="v2">
      <ele1 line="1">
         <ele2/>
      </ele1>
   </rnp>
   <Request xmlns="v1">
      <Request xmlns="v2"/>
      <Info>
         <Country>US</Country>
         <Part>A</Part>
      </Info>
   </Request>
</enc>
```

**Excepted output**

Note:In Request tag , i want 'v1' to be replaced by 'v2' and here i want to delete the duplicate(which i existing)

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<enc xmlns="v9">
   <rnp xmsns="v2">
      <ele1 line="1">
         <ele2/>
      </ele1>
   </rnp>
   <Request xmlns="v2">
      <Info>
         <Country>US</Country>
         <Part>A</Part>
      </Info>
   </Request>
</enc>
```

I want to replace the xmlns of specfic tag
**Thanks in advance**

Comment: *"This is output which i am getting"* I don't think so. Your stylesheet will produce an error because `xmlns` is not a valid attribute name.

Comment: oh , i tried with vs code extension, it works , shows a output

Answer (score 1):

Use templates to match the elements in the old namespace and `xsl:element` to output result elements in the new namespace:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:old="v1"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="old:*">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="v2">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: this i had already tried ,this xsl is changing all xmlns ,i want to change the specfic xmlns tag

Comment: @sss, no idea what is a specific "xmlns tag", but at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVAkJ4r it looks to me as if the code I suggested gives the result you wanted for the posted input.

Comment: you are correct ,actually i had problem with my complier ,Thanks for u r time